# Appending a File with int 0x80 (Access bits?)

Tags: assembly, nasm

In my NASM textbook, *"Guide to Assembly Programming in Linux"* by Dandamundi, system call 5 (opening a file) is described with the following parameters.

```
EAX = 5
EBX = file name
ECX = file access mode (read, write, read/write)
EDX = file permissions
```

It does not clarify what the access codes (octal, I'm assuming) actually are. 0200Q and 02000Q assumedly do not work. I am trying to append the contents of one file onto another file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at `/usr/include/asm/unistd_32.h`, it's clear that system call number 5 resolves to `open`. In turn, looking at `man 2 open` says that the second parameter must include `O_RDONLY` (`00`), `O_WRONLY` (`01`) or `O_RDWR` (`02`). It may also include a number of extra flags by ORing them together, which are documented on the said manual page.

In your case, you probably want to be able to write to a file and append to it. Therefore, `O_WRONLY | O_APPEND` would be desirable. After looking at the header files, that operation yields the value `02001` and this is what you should put in the `ecx` register.

Comment: Thank you very much!
`mov ECX, 02001Q` 
works perfectly and my program works.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the `sys_open` syscall, so the parameters should map one-to-one to those of [open(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open):

> The argument *flags* must include one of the following access modes:
>   O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, or O_RDWR. These request opening the file
>   read-only, write-only, or read/write, respectively.  In addition, zero
>   or more file creation flags and file status flags can be bitwise-or'd
>   in flags. The file creation flags are O_CREAT, O_EXCL, O_NOCTTY, and
>   O_TRUNC. ...